# Getting 500 internal error by using recursive function

Tags: php, recursion

I've got internal error when calling below recursive function.
Below function is checking for reference id (one type of parent id) in matrix table that if reference id available in matrix table then execution should over and return that id but if not found that id in matrix table then again take reference id(enroller_id) from members table of that old reference id(stored in $ref_id) and call again that function and it's continue calling until it gets that particular id is available or not in matrix and at the end if it's not found then it'll return default id($default_ref_id).

But I don't know why I'm getting internal server error there I've also tried by increasing max_execution_time 30 to 50 OR 100 but couldn't fix that.

Please it would be great if you can help me with that I've been stuck with this issue since from last 3 to 4 hours.

Here is function I've created there :

```
function findReferralMember($ref_id)
{

  $default_ref_id=1;

  $count_ref_member = GetSingleValue("matrix","Count(*)","member_id='".$ref_id."'");


 if($count_ref_member > 0)
 {
    return $ref_id;
 }
 else
 {
    $ref_id = GetSingleValue("members","enroller_id","member_id='".$ref_id."'");

    findReferralMember($ref_id);
 }

 return $default_ref_id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is in an endless loop.**

Each call to the function `findReferralMember` is calling `findReferralMember` again.  The `$count_ref_member` variable is never greater than zero.  This endless loop is never returning, and eventually blows out the stack on the server.  This is what is returning the 500 error message.

Trace through your code and see why this infinite loop is happening.  Fix the infinite loop and the 500 error will go away.